# How to reduce element height proportionally while scrolling limited by a scroll and height range in javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, scroll, algebra

I have an element with a height of 100, when the window scroll exceed 70px the height should be reduced proportionally to reach 40 when scroll reach 200px.

```
scroll = 70px => height = 100
window.scrollY = 90 => y = ?
scroll = 200px => height = 400
```

this is my code:

```
function whileScrolling () {
   if(window.scrollY < 70) {
      newHeight = 100
   } else  if (window.scrollY > 200) {
      newHeight = 40
   } else if (window.scrollY > 70) {
      const scrollRange = {
         min: 70,
         max: 200
      };
      const heightRange = {
         min: 40,
         max: 100
      }
      let currentScroll = window.scrollY

      newHeight = ?

   }
}
```

fire onScrolling

How to calculate y?

Comment: that's a simple mathematical proportion..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, Linear equation:

```
y=-6/13*currentScroll+1720/13;
```

The reason for the not-so-pretty numbers is the `70px`. If you chose, say, `50px` instead, the numbers would be much prettier (but maybe the resulting website wont be. It's up to you...)

But you should also keep the limits:

```
scroll <= 70px => height = 100
scroll >= 200px => height = 40
```

And then it's limited at those scrolls.

You don't really need the `scrollRange` or the last `else if`.

```
function whileScrolling () {
   if(window.scrollY < 70) {
      newHeight = 100;
   } else  if (window.scrollY > 200) {
      newHeight = 40;
   } else {

      let currentScroll = window.scrollY

      newHeight = -6/13*currentScroll+1720/13;

   }
}
```

Those numbers are calculated like this:

Points `A` and `B` are `(scroll: 70, height: 100)`,`(scroll: 200, height: 40)`.
The line between them is the relation between the scroll and the wanted height. From there it's math: the slope is `(40-100)/(200-70)` which is `-6/13`. And the `1720` comes from the algebra of the line equation.

[image]

Comment: Thank for the help, i didn't understand your solution, i added code maybe it will help?

Comment: @Salimd83 could you please show the relevant html in your question? maybe a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Salimd83 width? I thought you were asking about height.

Comment: yes it about height, just made a mistake. and im using react with jsx, i don't want complicate the question. By including not related code, i just want the algebra

Comment: Where are you getting those numbers: -6, 13 and 1720? let me understand the logic please

Comment: @Salimd83 I'll upload a drawing in a moment. It's a mathematical problem, not so much related to coding.

Comment: works perfectly, many thanks. But I still doesn't understand how 1720 is calculated, to be able to solve other similar situations, if you could explain please

Comment: @Salimd83 I created a chat room for this, to prevent an extended discussion . I'd be glad to help you there: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150963/discussion-between-itamarg3-and-salimd83